# How to use react-router v4 Promt

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my app I have a number of forms on different pages. I would like to add in an alert notification to users if they have made a change to a form that hasn't been saved. React router v4 appears to have this function built in `<Promt>`, however, I've tried putting it in my `App Router` component and within the form and it returns an error `ReferenceError: formIsHalfFilledOut is not defined`. How do I use this correctly

EG: `Wihtin form`

```
render() {
  return (
    <Form className="languageForm" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
      <SingleInput inputType={'text'} controlFunc={this.handleLanguageChange(language.uniqueId)} content={language.language} placeholder={'Language'} bsSize={null} error={language.errors && language.errors.language}/>
      <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Save"/>
      <Prompt when={formIsHalfFilledOut} message="Are you sure you want to leave?"/>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

EG: `Within App.jsx`

```
const App = appProps => (
  <Router>
    <Prompt when={formIsHalfFilledOut} message="Are you sure you want to leave?"/>
    <NavBar {...appProps}/>
    <Grid className="main-page-container">
      <Switch>
        <Authenticated exact path="/" component={Home} {...appProps}/>
        <Authenticated exact path="/admin/profile_candidate/edit/contact_details" component={ContactDetailsFormContainer} {...appProps}/>
        <Authenticated exact path="/admin/profile_candidate/edit/summary" component={SummaryFormContainer} {...appProps}/>
        <Route render={function() {
          return <p>Page not found</p>;
        }}/>
      </Switch>
    </Grid>
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the reason why is this happening, is because of you not declared your `formIsHalfFilledOut` variable.

The name for this variable (as I understood) being setted like this implying the situation when you were filling some form/fields etc, but leaving by the link, possibly unfinished.

Codepen example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qxQKOZ

Code:

```
const {
  HashRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link, Prompt
} = ReactRouterDOM

class YourForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      formIsHalfFilledOut: false,
      value: ''
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let value = event.target.value;

    this.setState((prevState)=>{
      let isNotFilled = (value === '');
      return {
          formIsHalfFilledOut: !isNotFilled,
          value: value
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {title} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
                <Prompt when={this.state.formIsHalfFilledOut} message="Are you sure?"/>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <div>
          <Link to="/">Some link</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render((
  <HashRouter>
    <YourForm title="I'm the form" />
  </HashRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

P.S.
It's probably to late now, but I found this question while being researching about `<Prompt>` and stuff